# Homeomorphism from $K$ to $\Phi_{C(K)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff and $C(K)$ be a Banach algebra of continuous function on $K$ such that $\textbf{1} \in C(K)$ and such that $C(K)$ separates the point of $K$. I am trying to show that $\delta : K \rightarrow \Phi_{C(K)}$ is a homeomorphism where $\Phi_{C(K)}$ is the space of characters on $C(K)$ and $\delta(K) = \delta_k$ the evaluation at $k$.

So far I showed that $\delta$ is a bijection between $K$ which is compact and $\Phi_{C(K)}$ which is Hausdorff.

All I need to do is to show that $\delta$ is continuous but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the easy part. The topology you need to consider on $\Phi_{C(K)}$ is the weak* topology; that is, pointwise convergence.

So, if $x_j\to x$ in $K$, you want to show that $\delta_{x_j}\to\delta_x$. This means that $\delta_{x_j}(f)\to\delta_x(f
)$ for all $f\in C(K)$. But this is $f(x_j)\to f(x)$, which is precisely the continuity of $f$.

Conversely, if $\delta_{x_j}\to\delta_x$ you have  $f (x_j)\to f (x) $ for every  $f\in C (K) $. Then  $x_j\to x $ by Urysohn's Lemma.

Comment: Is sequential continuity enough to conclude that $\delta$ is a homeomorphism ?

Comment: No, it isn't. I never mentioned sequences,  though. You also need to address the continuity of the inverse, see the edit.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You showed that $x_j \rightarrow x$ in $X$ implies $\delta_{x_j}\rightarrow \delta_x$, isn't 'sequential continuity' rather than 'continuity' ? If $K$ is metrizable than these are equivalent but what if $K$ is not metrizable ?

Comment: It would be sequential continuity if $\{x_j\} $ was a sequence. Being a net, it tests plain continuity.

Comment: Interesting! I got to read more about nets. Thank you.